# How to output one value from a dictionary whose key has two values

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, output, key-value

I'm working on a text-based game project for school and I'm trying to pull one value from my dictionary. The value I'm trying to pull is "gun" and not both "Lobby" and "gun". The output is: "You see: Lobby Gun". The output I want is: "You see: Gun". Is that possible? Thank you.

```
rooms = {
        'Lobby': {'North': 'Teller Room', 'South': 'Vestibule', 'East': 'Office 1', 'West': 'Office 2'},
         'Vestibule': {'North': 'Lobby'},
        'Office 2': {'East': 'Lobby', 'Item': 'Gun'},
         'Office 1': {'North': 'Bathroom', 'Item': 'Gloves'},
         'Bathroom': {'West': 'Lobby', 'Item': 'Keys'},
         'Teller Room': {'South': 'Lobby', 'East': 'Utility Room', 'West': 'Vault', 'Item': 'Bags'},
        'Utility Room': {'West': 'Teller Room', 'Item': 'Knife'},
         'Vault': {'East': 'Teller Room', 'Item': 'Money'}

}


   collection = rooms['Office 2'].values()
   print('You see: ', *collection)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to print is the item, then you should just print the item:

```
collection = rooms['Office 2']['Item']
```

Since not all rooms have an item, you'll need to check that.

Comment: `rooms["office2"].get("Item","nothing")` maybe?

Comment: As a followup, allow me to suggest that you consider defining some object classes here.  You could have a "Room" class and an "Item" class, and keep the implementation hidden, while allowing more flexibility internally.  Your "maze" object could then be a list of Rooms.  Your current designed requires ALL the code that uses the `rooms` dict to have a detailed understanding of the internals.

Answer (score 0):

> How to output one value from a dictionary whose key has two values

This appears to be a misunderstanding. All dictionary keys always have one value. In other words, when you do `rooms['Office 2']`, you only get one value. In this case, that value is another dictionary with its own keys an values. So when you do `rooms['Office 2'].values()`, you will get all of the values from the dictionary referred by `rooms['Office 2']`.

If that's not what you want, you should do something different with that dictionary such as only print out the item with `print(rooms['Office 2']['Item'])`. You might want to update your inner dictionaries so that they all have an `'Item'` key. If there is no item in the room, you can add `'Item': None` to indicate this.

Side note, now that you are getting the hang of dictionaries, you should learn about classes. They provide a mechanism to represent objects in your game directly in code. For example, you could make `class Room` to represent a room in the game. This is often preferred over dictionaries because you can encapsulate data and behavior in a class.